# I need a calendar that lets me drag and drop files into it as events

Tags: file-management, file-synchronization, calendar, scheduling, google-calendar

I'll get straight to the point. There's out there a calendar app that:

- Lets me drag and drop files into it, creating a 'file event' (I'm aware of the file attachments in Google Calendar, but since I'm going to handle a lot of files a drag n drop solution is widely more acceptable for me)
- Lets me rearrange 'file events' simply by dragging them over days and hours
- Plus: Automatically adds a checklist to each item
- Plus: Syncs with Google Calendar and the attachments thing

I'm on Windows, but a web app is also ok - I'm not talking about huge filesizes. Preferably free and open source, but everything is ok since I'm not able to find a solution.